# Сохранение имени картинки в базе данных

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, сохраняю и записываю картинку к записи в бд.

В имени нужно использовать id, который бд автоинкрементирует после сохранения записи, т.е. получить id до сохранения я не могу.

Вопрос: можно ли так делать и делают ли так вообще?

```
public function saveCategory()
{
    $this->image_url = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image_url');
    $dir = "uploads/categories";
    if ($this->image_url && $this->validate()) {
        $image_url = $this->image_url;
        if ($this->save()) {
            $name = "$this->id.$image_url->extension";
            $this->image_url = $name;
            $this->save();
            $image_url->saveAs("$dir/$name");
        }
    }
    else {
        $model = Categories::findOne($this->id);
        if ($model->image_url) {
            $this->image_url = $model->image_url;
        }
        $this->save();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Конкретно вот это место:

```
        if ($this->save()) {
            $name = "$this->id.$image_url->extension";
            $this->image_url = $name;
            $this->save();
            $image_url->saveAs("$dir/$name");
        }
```

Comment: Сначала сохраняете основную модель, если модель сохранена, получаете ее `id`. Потом уже сохраняете картинку с полученным `id`

Comment: @robertobadjo, значит ничего плохого нету в двойном сохранении?

Comment: Больше никак. А зачем Вам `id` записи в `image_url`? При получении картинки, можно просто конкатенировать с `id` записи

Comment: @robertobadjo, конкатенировать что? baseName? оно мне не нужно. я сохраняю категорию, после чего сохраняю картинку с id категории в имени, чтобы можно было определить, какая картинка к какой категории относится.

Comment: Дак и так понятно какая картинка к какой категории относится, при выборке из БД у Вас есть ее `id`, который соответствует `id` категории.

Comment: @robertobadjo,я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите мне сказать. у меня нету id картинки, я записываю имя картинки в одной таблице с категорией, в поле image_url.

Comment: Зачем Вам здесь: `$name = "$this->id.$image_url->extension";`  `id` категории? Чтобы понять к какой категории относится картинка? Покажите мне код где Вы используете данное поле

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83262/discussion-between-dasauser-and-robertobadjo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ответ из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882239/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?noredirect=1#comment1435636_882239))

Сначала сохраняете основную модель, если модель сохранена, получаете ее `id`. Потом уже сохраняете картинку с полученным `id`.
Больше никак.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно делать и так делают, но это просто **дикий ужас** и от такого подхода надо отказываться или хотя бы начинать отказываться.

Метод `saveCategory()` для чего написан? Метод ради метода? Категория и картинка это разные сущности и их надо хранить в разных таблицах. У категории есть id, name, parent и все, остальные данные (какие бы они не были) к сущности категория не относятся. За уши можно притащить что угодно, но это добавит только ужаса в код.

В данном случае я бы рекомендовал использовать две разные таблицы, а логику сохранения можно и нужно описать в behavior. Используя событие `afterSave` сохранить картинку и связать две эти сущности (категорию и картинку) через промежуточную таблицу. Получать данные картинки необходимо через реляцию с использованием метода `via()` или метода `viaTable()`. Методы для получения с использованием промежуточной таблицы.

Таким образом получится чистая и аккуратная категория, чистая аккуратная картинка. Бихевиор можно прицепить к другой сущности (например раздел) и не будет необходимости писать еще один метод с корявой логикой сохранения и кучей ифов.

Рекомендую изучить или хотя бы познакомиться с принципами **SOLID**

Comment: этот ответ верен для проектов разрабатываемых с нуля. мне же, разрабатывая (а точнее перерабатывая) функционал уже к готовой базе, будет очень неудобно разрабатывать новую структуру, но в будущем постараюсь делать так, как вы описали. однако мне кажется смежная таблица будет лишней, т.к. к одной категории - одна картинка.